# How to allow a user to remove or add fields into grouping in protected sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to allow users to add or remove their own choice of fields in grouping in a protected sheet.

```
Sub AllowGroupUngroupInProtectedSheet()
With Activesheet
  .Protect SheetPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
  .EnableOutlining = True
End With
```

I know above code allows a user to group/ungroup the fields by clicking the `+` button. But the user can't add/remove their choice of fields.